# WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

Tags: java, redis, jedis

I am looping through an arrayList and using redis rpush function to store strings in redis .However,I am getting the following error: WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value

```
 for(String abc:myList) {
    jedis.rpush(abc,(String[]) myList.toArray(new String[myList.size()]));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please properly format your input instead of just dumping all these different things in the same way. There is a nice help text explaining formatting rules here and a very helpful preview window, too.

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite literal and self explanatory - the key you're trying to use is of the wrong type (not a list). You can verify that by using the [`TYPE`](https://redis.io/commands/type) command on that key.